# How to check approximate number and partition key of wide rows

Tags: cassandra

Is there any way i can get the count or approximate number and partition key of wide rows per table in Cassandra before system.log's warning about "compacting large partition" and apart from nodetool cfstats's output "compacted partition bytes" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can pull the metric from jmx, there is a MaxPartitionSize and EstimatedPartitionSizeHistogram which are what cfstats is displaying. The EstimatedPartitionSizeHistogram is hard to parse, but it will show the number of partitions at each size (+ or - 20%), this can also be displayed by using `nodetool tablehistograms` (cfhistograms).

There are many jmx reporting tools you can use to plug into whatever your using for alerts. Be good to set a safe threshold like 100mb at first. If on 3.11 (or any 3.6+) the threshold where thats safe increases significantly (~1gb).